# Best way to set action listeners to many buttons

Tags: java, swing, listeners

I have not worked with button listeners hardly at all, and have been looking online for at least 3 hours trying to figure something out, I have resorted to asking for help here

Can someone show me the best way to add an action to each button within my panel class.

here is what I have so far.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class theClass extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

private JButton S, j ,O

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {



}
```

}

Comment: *"have been looking online for at least 3 hours trying to figure something out"*  Where have you been looking?  URLs please.  This kind of statement is typical of someone who has done 0 research but just wants others to spoon-feed information to them.

Comment: Your question asks for "the best way" but your code shows that you haven't done it at all. So it seems more like you're just asking for "a way". How to add an action listener to a JButton is covered in [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

Comment: _"have been looking online for at least 3 hours"_ - Did you look at the JButton API? It has links to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Buttons` or `How to Use Actions`. They would be a good places to start.

Comment: In the future, you'll get better help if you show your attempt to solve it first. If you don't do this, how will we know where you're stuck or what confuses you? Also your showing your effort gains much in terms of respect for you and your question, showing that you're willing to put in the effort and initiative to try to solve it yourself first.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to add your `ActionListener` to your `JButton`s - like this:

```
Soda.addActionListener(this);
```

Then you have to declare what to do on a click:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
  if(arg0.getSource().equals(Soda)){
    //Do sth...
  }// And so on using else if.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple different ways of doing this, the simplest way to go from where you currently are is to add this line:

```
Space.addActionListener(this);
```

You can add that line for each of your buttons and then you can in your `actionPerformed` method use code like this:

```
if (arg0.getSource() == Space) {
    // do stuff for click on space
}
else if (arg0.getSource() == Soda) {
    // do stuff for click on soda...
}
```

A general suggestion is to keep your variable names (Soda, Space, AddBevarages...) with a lowercase beginning letter as per the Java coding conventions.

Once you have finished your code and it is working the way you want it to, you might want to post a question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and asking for suggestions on how the code can be cleaned up and improved. But step one is always to *make it work first*.